# Using specific version of local NPM dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I have a local package `Foo`, and a dependency to it defined as follows (package.json):

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "file:../Foo"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now I would like to define a *specific* version of this local dependency, e.g. `"foo": "file:../Foo:0.1.0"`.

This syntax didn't work, and I couldn't find any examples from NPM's documentation. Does NPM support this when using `"file:"` -syntax? I'm using NPM v.5.6.0.

Comment: Yes, it supports file syntax since version 2.0.0 of npm. Please check other options from my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To clarify my question, the question is does "file:" -syntax support declaring wanted package version, i.e. it would check from dependency's package.json to have correct version, or fail if it is not satisfied?

Comment: File basically is for the local package, which is not published yet.

Answer (score 0):

### There are several ways:

1. **Link**ing the package: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link
2. **Save** it

   npm install --save ../your-local-repo
3. Use it in **Package.json**

   or this :

   {
     "name": "baz",
     "dependencies": {
       "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
     }
   }
4. **lib-manager**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lib-manager

**Automated postinstall**

```
npm install lib-manager --save-dev
```

Best way to use this module is to include the local-link command from your app's node_modules.bin folder as part of your postinstall script in your main package.json, like so:

```
{  
    "name": "myModule",  
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "README",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/local-link",
    "test": ""
     }
}
```

***Hope this helps you!***